# Anonymous user in Realm Mobile Platform

Tags: swift, realm, realm-mobile-platform

Can I connect to a remote Realm without having to login?

In Swift, the only way to create a synchronizable Realm is through the `syncConfiguration` property of a `Realm.Configuration`. Is there a method for getting an anonymous User so that anyone can connect to the remote Realm?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Can I connect to a remote Realm without having to login?

No, you always need to be authenticated.

> Is there a method for getting an anonymous User so that anyone can connect to the remote Realm?

Yes, via `SyncCredentials.anonymous()`.

Answer (score 2):

This is now possible in [Realm Cloud](https://realm.io/products/realm-platform/). Here's how I am doing it in Swift:

```
if let user = SyncUser.current {
  //--== User available ==--
  let config = Realm.Configuration(syncConfiguration: SyncConfiguration(user: user, realmURL: "..."))

  Realm.Configuration.defaultConfiguration = config
  let _ = try! Realm()

}else{
  //--== No User; Connect Anonymously ==--
  let credentials = SyncCredentials.anonymous()

  SyncUser.logIn(with: credentials, server: "...") { user, error in
    DispatchQueue.main.async {
      if let user = user {
        let config = Realm.Configuration(syncConfiguration: SyncConfiguration(user: user, realmURL: "..."))
        Realm.Configuration.defaultConfiguration = config
        let _ = try! Realm()

        }else{
          //Error...
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Good luck!