# Share database with other users using Realm Android?

Tags: android, database, realm

I am using Realm 2.0.0 for android.

I succeeded Authenticating feature and synchronizing realm database for individual users, but I could not find any info about sharing database with others.

How can I share databases with registered users?

Comment: why cant you create a single database in server ?

Comment: No not admin, I want accessible database created by users.
Thanks for reply :-)

Comment: why do you want to access database ? you can access the data right ?

Comment: I can access data with my realm account only, I want to share one database with two users.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Share realm between different users on Realm Object Server?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39756637/share-realm-between-different-users-on-realm-object-server)

Comment: I think this is a duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39756637/share-realm-between-different-users-on-realm-object-server/